# How to add a button ("X") - close window, close operation?

Tags: javascript, html, button

How to add a button ("X") - close window, close operation to this slider? This button has view look like ('X'). Please suggest me a way to improve this code.

```
</script>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();"><</button>
    <div id="scr"></div>
    <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();">></button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know do you mean something like this

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();"><</button>
    <div id="scr"></div>
    <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();">></button>
    <button class="close" onclick="slider.close();">X</button>
</div>  
</body>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.left, .right, .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
}

.close {
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w58vxuft/